# Cycle inside ARVideoKit; building could produce unreliable results

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I have encountered the issue while building a project in Xcode. It says "Cycle inside ARVideoKit; building could produce unreliable results. This usually can be resolved by moving the target's Headers build phase Compile Sources."

I've done so by looking into the build orders of ARVideoKit, I've moved the Headers in front of compile Sources. But the issue still persists.

Any tips would be greatly appreacited.

[image]

Below are the detailed error messages:

```
Showing Recent Messages
Cycle inside ARVideoKit; building could produce unreliable results. This usually can be resolved by moving the target's Headers build phase before Compile Sources.
Cycle details:
→ Target 'ARVideoKit' has link command with output '/Users/richardmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AR_Remote_Support-aaanobrrwbejkycmcyjzmsmrwiic/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ARVideoKit.framework/ARVideoKit'
○ Target 'ARVideoKit' has compile command with input '/Users/richardmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AR_Remote_Support-aaanobrrwbejkycmcyjzmsmrwiic/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ARVideoKit.build/Debug-iphoneos/ARVideoKit.build/DerivedSources/ARVideoKit_vers.c'
○ Target 'ARVideoKit' has compile command for Swift source files
○ Target 'ARVideoKit' has copy command from '/Users/richardmac/Documents/GitHub/ARVideoKit/ARVideoKit/ARVideoKit.h' to '/Users/richardmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AR_Remote_Support-aaanobrrwbejkycmcyjzmsmrwiic/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ARVideoKit.framework/Headers/ARVideoKit.h'


Raw dependency cycle trace:

target:  ->

node: <all> ->

command: <all> ->

node: /Users/richardmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AR_Remote_Support-aaanobrrwbejkycmcyjzmsmrwiic/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ARVideoKit.framework/ARVideoKit ->

command: target-ARVideoKit-2bded4ab62199ada5f79527c1e5e4d0e2e48c26ea4c59645a2f99f2829476ecd-:Debug:Ld /Users/richardmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AR_Remote_Support-aaanobrrwbejkycmcyjzmsmrwiic/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ARVideoKit.framework/ARVideoKit normal ->

CYCLE POINT ->

node: /Users/richardmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AR_Remote_Support-aaanobrrwbejkycmcyjzmsmrwiic/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ARVideoKit.build/Debug-iphoneos/ARVideoKit.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ARVideoKit_vers.o ->

command: target-ARVideoKit-2bded4ab62199ada5f79527c1e5e4d0e2e48c26ea4c59645a2f99f2829476ecd-:Debug:CompileC /Users/richardmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AR_Remote_Support-aaanobrrwbejkycmcyjzmsmrwiic/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ARVideoKit.build/Debug-iphoneos/ARVideoKit.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ARVideoKit_vers.o /Users/richardmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AR_Remote_Support-aaanobrrwbejkycmcyjzmsmrwiic/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ARVideoKit.build/Debug-iphoneos/ARVideoKit.build/DerivedSources/ARVideoKit_vers.c normal arm64 c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler ->

node: <target-ARVideoKit-2bded4ab62199ada5f79527c1e5e4d0e2e48c26ea4c59645a2f99f2829476ecd--generated-headers> ->

command: Gate target-ARVideoKit-2bded4ab62199ada5f79527c1e5e4d0e2e48c26ea4c59645a2f99f2829476ecd--generated-headers ->

node: /Users/richardmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AR_Remote_Support-aaanobrrwbejkycmcyjzmsmrwiic/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ARVideoKit.build/Debug-iphoneos/ARVideoKit.build/Objects-normal/arm64/UIView+isType.o ->

command: target-ARVideoKit-2bded4ab62199ada5f79527c1e5e4d0e2e48c26ea4c59645a2f99f2829476ecd-:Debug:CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler ->

node: /Users/richardmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AR_Remote_Support-aaanobrrwbejkycmcyjzmsmrwiic/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ARVideoKit.framework/Headers/ARVideoKit.h ->

command: target-ARVideoKit-2bded4ab62199ada5f79527c1e5e4d0e2e48c26ea4c59645a2f99f2829476ecd-:Debug:CpHeader /Users/richardmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AR_Remote_Support-aaanobrrwbejkycmcyjzmsmrwiic/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ARVideoKit.framework/Headers/ARVideoKit.h /Users/richardmac/Documents/GitHub/ARVideoKit/ARVideoKit/ARVideoKit.h ->

node: <target-ARVideoKit-2bded4ab62199ada5f79527c1e5e4d0e2e48c26ea4c59645a2f99f2829476ecd--phase0-compile-sources> ->

command: Gate target-ARVideoKit-2bded4ab62199ada5f79527c1e5e4d0e2e48c26ea4c59645a2f99f2829476ecd--phase0-compile-sources ->

node: /Users/richardmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AR_Remote_Support-aaanobrrwbejkycmcyjzmsmrwiic/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ARVideoKit.build/Debug-iphoneos/ARVideoKit.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ARVideoKit_vers.o
```